# Serilog MSSql sink doesn't work when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, serilog

I have a .Net framework web application being deployed to an Azure app service. I am trying to use the MSSql Serilog sink to write log messages to a central database.

My configuration is setup correctly because the log table is created on startup, however when logging messages they do not show up in the database.

Logging locally to the same database works fine, but as soon as the app is deployed to an App Service it doesn't work.

I have tried using the Serilog self log to write to Trace, but nothing appears in any log files on the log stream, application logs or anywhere else.

I have confirmed the connection string is correct, and logging is enabled. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

My log config:

```
var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
logConfig = logConfig.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
    connectionString: "ConnectionString",
    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
    {
        TableName = "Log",
        AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
    });
Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Could you add the app setting configuration details in the question?

Comment: I'm not using app setting config for serilog, just code config.